# Test for overlap between two sets of hypothesis tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, paired-comparisons

I'm looking for the appropriate test for determining whether the overlap in variables in which the null hypothesis was rejected is greater than expected by chance for two identical *sets* of independent hypothesis tests.

**For example:**

Given gene expression data (20,000 variables) for 4 different conditions (A, B, C, D), we run a differential expression analysis for conditions A vs. B, and for conditions C vs. D.

For comparison A vs. B, we reject the null hypothesis for 3373 genes.

For comparisons C vs. D. we reject the null hypothesis for 900 genes.

We reject the null hypothesis for total of 430 genes in *both* comparisons:

```
                            | Genes with DE | Genes without DE |
                            |  in C vs. D   |    in C vs. D    |
----------------------------|---------------|------------------|
Genes with DE in A vs. B    |      430      |       2,943      |
----------------------------|---------------|------------------|
Genes without DE in A vs. B |      470      |      16,157      |      
----------------------------|---------------|------------------|
```

We want to test whether this number (430) is greater than expected by chance.

**Assumptions**:

- The same set of variables are tested independently in A vs. B and independently in C vs. D
- We are using the same significance threshold for both sets of tests
- The 20,000 tests within each comparison are independent

We've thought about using both the chi-square test and McNemar's test (considering the test for gene G in condition A vs. B as paired with the same test in C vs. D), but I'm not convinced either are appropriate.